# Importing a spreadsheet into an asp.net program and listing the worksheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have to import the contents of a spreadsheet in my asp.net project. The code behind is c#. I figured out how to locate the spreadsheet on the user's computer and how to import the data from a given worksheet into a datable. The problem is I may not know the name of the worksheet ahead of time. How do I present the user with a list of available worksheets and have them pick one?

Bob

Comment: Hi, Bob. Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to specify *how* you are reading the Excel document. Are you using COM interop or some third-party library?

Comment: Sure.

I'm using 

 OleDbConnection objConn = null;
 objConn = new OleDbConnection(pConnectionString);

where 


pConnectionString =  "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=spreadsheet.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell the ASP.NET page where to look on the user's PC for a file. If so, there would be nothing stopping you from snooping the user's entire machine and gathering personal information.

Your option is present the user with a file upload control (the most practical being the asp:FileUpload server control) and allowing the user to select which file to submit. If you need a greater deal of control than that, you are going to have to use something other than (or in addition to) ASP.NET, such as a winform or console app that resides on the user's machine.

Comment: Hi Anthony, 

Thanks for responding. You seem to have misunderstood the question. I am not looking for how to find a file on the user's computer but rather how to list the worksheets in a spreadsheet than I've found.

By the way, I found that AsyncFileUpload works better than FileUpload . I've had problems getting FileUpload to work.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

OleDbConnection objConn = null;
 objConn = new OleDbConnection(pConnectionString);
// where pConnectionString looks like
// "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Source\Sheetname.xls;Extended 
//Properties=Excel 8.0;"
     // Opens connection with the database. 
     objConn.Open();
     // Get the data table containing the schema guid, and also sheet names. 
     dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

the rows of dt (a datatable contains the worksheet names)